# Python ctype directly call a function with raw offset

Tags: python, c++, function, raw-pointer

Is it possible to call a RAW function pointer inside python?

for example:

```
ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetModuleHandleA(None)
```

will call the API, Python resolves the DLL + Function pointer to make it work. but if I have a raw function pointer, for example 0xDEADBEEF (which corresponds to the function header) how do I create a funciton instance passing this raw pointer?

I can't just export the function since its located on a compiled executable, but I want to be able to do something like this:

To make it clear... in C++ I can call RAW function with something like this:

```
#define myfunction ((void(*)(int a, int b, int c)) 0x00402383)

myfunction(1, 2, 3);
```

I python I wanted to make something similar, maybe using ctypes library?
I've digged inside the library but I couldn't find how they initialize the function instance.

Notes:

- The python engine is embedded inside a DLL.
- The DLL is injected into the process I want to call the function address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the function is located in a compiled executable, then you can't, neither in C++ because you'll get an access violation. You can't call functions from another process.

If you have C++ knowledge then create a DLL and inject it into the executable. You'll be able to call it.

---

Since you've already injected your DLL into the target process, it seems to be possible to achieve what you want using ctypes.

```
>>> functype = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_int)
>>> func = functype(raw_address)
>>> func
<CFunctionType object at 0x1006816d0>
```

Comment: Thats the whole point. I already have the injected dll, and the python engine is embedded inside this dll. I just need to know how to call the executable's functions by creating a function instance with the raw address inside the python script.

Comment: @WoLfulus Not sure if you can using `ctypes`, but I you can do it in C++. Create a simple Python module in C++ and call it from your Python code!

Comment: I'm trying to do this inside python exactly to avoid changing the C++ code. Since ctypes is able to call any function from any dll, I believe there's a way to initialize a functionptr objects with the raw address and handles. I'm just not sure how.

Comment: @WoLfulus It seems like you can. See https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/python-cookbook-3rd/9781449357337/ch15s12.html .